# I can't get a div with role textbox, to flex upwards instead of downwards

Tags: html, css

When the textbox gets full, it starts going downwards, even if the main div has a steady width. I want it to instead flex upwards, something like Facebook when you keep typing something.

I tried making the class `"comment-sec"` absolute, but that just made everything messy.

I tried making the class `"comment-text"` absolute and added `bottom:0` that worked fine but now the div `"comment-sec"` will have a y-scroll that is out of position.

https://jsfiddle.net/sn1079ku/3/

I expect it to flex upwards like Facebook, but it goes downwards.

EDIT: forgot to mention its a picture description and comment section

Comment: Adding ```#comment{height: 80px;}``` in your css will make not go down. But won't grow up.

Comment: @B-M I guess then thats my only choice, oh well

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and it was to add `overflow: hidden` to the main div, with the class `picture-descript` and changed a few things here and there, like changed height to 70% on the class `comment-sec` and added a `max-height`. I also removed the class `wowserve`

https://jsfiddle.net/dprj8mfb/1/

Comment: It seems that it's still going down in the link you posted

Comment: @B-M It looks like it, but its actually going up, but tbh it did not even work. It does go up which is perfect, but it just pushes everything up and out of position. So i'm just using a steady height like you mentioned before.